# popViewController with pushViewController animation

Tags: iphone, ios, pushviewcontroller, popviewcontroller

I want to popViewController with pushViewController animation. Is there any way to do this? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

with a trick you can :)

get the viewcontroller which want to be visible after pop.

pop 2x without animation

push the targetviewcontroller animated, and you have the controller and the push animation :)

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Working 100 %

> list=[[List_ViewController
>   alloc]initWithNibName:@"List_ViewControlleripad" bundle:nil];
>       CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
>       transition.duration = 0.45;
>       transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
>       transition.type = kCATransitionFromLeft;
>       [transition setType:kCATransitionMoveIn];
>       transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
>       transition.delegate = self;
>       [self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
>       self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
>       [self.navigationController pushViewController:list animated:NO];

Answer (score 0):

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
 TargetViewCointroller *obj = [[TargetViewCointroller alloc]initWithNibName:@"TargetViewCointroller" bundle:nil];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];

   [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
     [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
     [obj_ release];
```

let me know is it working or not...
Happy Coding!!!!

Comment: I want the push animation while poping ... I dont want to allocate the TargetViewCointroller again